# どうして「〜たいくらいだ」には「くらい」が出るのですか

Tags: words, particle-くらい

最近「むしろあなたに英語を教えてもらいたいくらいだ」という文を見かけたのですけど、英訳の「I'd rather you teach me English」を言ってみたとしたら、私なら「くらいだ」なしで、「むしろあなたに英語を教えてもらいたい」とかになるでしょうから、「くらいだ」の働きや必要性に悩んでいるのです。この「くらい」は、最低限を表すものと同じなのですか。何か軽蔑を表しているわけですか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「くらい」には色々な意味があり、あるものの程度が非常に小さいことを表すことも、非常に大きいことを表すこともできます。

1. おおよそ同じ程度・approximately：「1年くらい前」「サッカーボールくらいのサイズ」
2. たったこれだけの程度・only：「それくらいのことで泣くな」「話を聞くくらいなら簡単だ」
3. こんなに大きな程度・this much・to the point：「驚くくらいに美しい」「1万円もするくらいだからおいしいはずだ」

あなたの例の場合は3番目に該当します。つまり、この「くらい」には、「聞き手の英語の**能力がとても高いので**」という気持ちが入っています。

> むしろあなたに英語を教えてもらいたい**くらい**だ。
>   (Your English is **so** good **that**) I'd rather have you teach me English.
>   (Your English is good **to the point where**) I'd rather have you teach me English.

この文は、事前に「あなたの英語は上手ですよ」のような文脈がある場合のみ成立します。