# What comes after this くらい

Tags: particle-くらい

In the sentence 燕もよくやるって他人事のように感じてしまうくらい in the below passage I am unclear as to what the implied bit after くらい is. The bit that confused me is that there is a full stop after くらい but then she continues on describing the way she has acted towards 燕, which is the sort of attitude that would make me wonder how he puts up with her.

> 燕は相変わらず優しい。学園祭の前だからあまり顔を出せないと言いながらも、電話はくれるし、言葉の節々からわたしへの気遣いを感じる。「腫れ物、なのよね…」。燕もよくやるって他人事のように感じてしまうくらい。嫌な態度をとって気を引こうとしたり、子供みたいな癇癪を起こしたり。甘えたり。燕にだけは自分でも信じられない態度ばかりをとってしまう。そのくせ、肝心な時には尻込みして。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, it *is* a complete sentence. Nothing can be attached to it anymore except a technically missing copula (だ/です etc.) and additional final particles (ね/よ etc.).

- [どうして「〜たいくらいだ」には「くらい」が出るのですか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64922/7810)

It then means that: "It is so much that 燕もよくやるって他人事のように感じてしまう". But of course this sentence needs an external standard of comparison from the context. If you prefer incorporating it, you can also understand it as such:

> 燕もよくやるって他人事のように感じてしまうくらい（に）、わたしへの気遣いを感じる。