# Meaning of くらい in this sentence

Tags: translation, words

## The Sentence

「君たちはお金をもらって会社で仕事を教えてもらい、鍛えられている。給料をもらうなんて話が逆だろう。**会社がもらいたいくらいだ**。授業料、持ってこい」

From my estimation (and thanks to [@chocolate](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/9831/chocolate)) this translates to: (?)

> You guys are paid to be taught the work and trained at the company. Getting paid? It's the other way around! The company would rather get it (the salary?). Bring/Hand the tuition fees!

Comment: Consider the 3rd definition here: https://takoboto.jp/?q=%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84 . I am not an expert, but it looks possible.

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64922/45489

Comment: "You **are paid to work for the company**, to be taught and trained." <-- Is that the official translation? お金をもらって会社で仕事を教えてもらい鍛えられている means "You get money, and you are taught the work and trained in the company, / You are paid to be taught the work and trained at the company".

Comment: @Chocolate , this was my attempt to translate the whole sentence and try to get a grasp. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @sundowner Does this fit the 3d case meaning "rather": "The company would rather receive it (money) from you".

Comment: Yes, *rather* works, but note that it is a matter of translation. くらい itself should be *to the extent*. ("The company is doing so much that it would like *you* to pay")

Comment: @sundowner Thanks again for the clarification! This has been very useful!